# Scatterpie plots appear as lines on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatterpie

I have data like this

```
     year month Avdischarge IndustrialCompound Pharmaceutical Pesticide TotalOvershootings
37 2018     1    740.5200          0.0000000      1.0000000 0.0000000          0.1578947
38 2018     2    376.8050          0.0000000      1.0000000 0.0000000          0.1428571
39 2018     3    269.2800          0.4285714      0.5714286 0.0000000          0.2800000
40 2018     4    195.8825          0.0000000      1.0000000 0.0000000          0.2105263
41 2018     5    100.9800          0.2500000      0.5833333 0.1666667          0.3243243
42 2018     6     99.5775          0.0000000      1.0000000 0.0000000          0.2105263
```

I first plotted the discharge

```
q<- ggplot(data,aes(month, Avdischarge, group=1))+
            geom_line(color='royalblue1', size=1.5, alpha=0.9))
```

Now I want to add a `scatterpie` plot to the discharge plot

So I did this

```
    pieper<-q + 
scatterpie::geom_scatterpie(aes(x=month, y=2, group=type, r = TotalOvershootings/0.5), 
                                            cols= c("IndustrialCompound", "Pharmaceutical", "Pesticide"),alpha= 0.7, color=NA,data= data)
```

But I get this

[image: example]

I already changed the `r` to every possible number, but I don't get the pies correctly(like in the picture). When I change the r the pies become larger, but always as a line, or disappear.

What can I add, so I can get the pie charts in a correct scale?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a scaling problem. If you just plot

```
q<- ggplot(data,aes(month, Avdischarge, group=1))+
  scatterpie::geom_scatterpie(aes(x=month, y=2, group=type, r = TotalOvershootings/0.5),
                          cols= c("IndustrialCompound", "Pharmaceutical", "Pesticide"),alpha= 0.7, color=NA,data= data)
```

it prints everything as circles. Do you see the colors at the bottom of your chart? These are the circles. Look at the y-axis then you see that the circles have another scale.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add the  scale_y_log10() to the code  to solve this scale problem.(the y in your first plot is too big, whereas the y in your second plot is too little! so try to adjust their scales by using scale_y_log10() properly~